# How to get full cxx -std= flag inside CMAKE?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, cmake, clang

How can I get full option string "-std=..." after
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17) ?
String with a flag must be obtained inside CmakeLists.txt.

Comment: It is need for build precompilled headers. Actually possible use may be different.

Comment: To generate, build and integrate PCHs with CMake with minimal effort have a look at [cotire](https://github.com/sakra/cotire).

Answer (score 0):

"$(CXX_FLAGS)" (round brackets important) contains "-std=..." flag and expand inside a makefile.