# How do I get the C++ standard flag as a string in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I need to get the compiler flags that will be used to compile a target programmatically in CMake. I need these flags as a string because I need to pass them to an executable in a custom command that needs to know how the parent target was compiled because it propagates those flags. I know enabling compile commands generates a JSON that shows the compile command but I need that output in CMake itself.

```
project(foo LANGUAGES CXX)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

add_executable(bar bar.cpp)

# define COMPILE_FLAGS somehow such that it equals -std=c++17    

add_custom_target(external
    COMMAND external_exe --flags ${COMPILE_FLAGS}
)
```

I've looked at these previous questions:

- Using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56104607/how-to-print-current-compilation-flags-that-are-set-with-target-compile-options) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61434756/how-to-print-all-compile-options-in-cmake) does print compile flags like "-Werror" but the standard flag is not printed
- [Setting the standard with set_property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57607466/how-to-get-cmake-generate-std-c14-flag-for-qcc-compiler) and then getting it returns "17". Similarly, I can get the CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD to also return "17"*
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361950/how-to-get-full-cxx-std-flag-inside-cmake) is the exact problem I have but the answer doesn't help in CMake
- These questions are also related but unhelpful: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62753194/cmake-get-all-flags-includes-and-defines-programatically), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51769184/how-to-get-all-compilation-flags-for-current-build-type), and [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623354/get-build-command-or-all-compiler-flags-that-will-be-used-to-build-a-target)

Am I missing something or is there no way to get this information?

*Can I assume that getting the standard number (e.g. 17) and appending that to "-std=c++" will be portably valid? It works with g++ at least but I'm not sure about other compilers/platforms.

Comment: Looks like a XY-problem. If your code needs knowing the C++ standard version, the macro `__cplusplus` is for this purpose.

Comment: I need the standard information for an external command-line executable so the ``__cplusplus`` macro doesn't help

Comment: "I need that output in CMake itself." - In general, it is impossible to get compile flags, created by CMake, while processing `CMakeLists.txt`. CMake computes these flags **after** the configuration process is finished. Exactly at that stage all linked libraries are known and generator expressions can be expanded.

Comment: Good to know. I don't need all the compile flags (and not any linker / flags that are being transitively inherited etc), just the standard flag. I would have assumed that information is available since I'm defining the standard up front

Comment: Do you need `--flags --std=c++${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD}`?

Comment: @273K Yes, I need that string. The second part of my question was whether constructing it like that was portably valid across different compilers/platforms

Comment: beware that gcc [8-9] use `c++2a` then later `c++20`, cmake correctly do the job after detecting the compiler...
ref: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need the compiler flag for choosing the C++ standard, try this:

```
set(COMPILE_FLAG ${CMAKE_CXX${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD}_STANDARD_COMPILE_OPTION})
```

Alternatively, replace "STANDARD" in the code above with "EXTENSION" if you want to allow compiler-specific extensions.

I grepped through the CMake source code, and I found that variables like `CMAKE_CXX17_STANDARD_COMPILE_OPTION` are defined in files that tell CMake how to use different compilers.

Comment: Is this a reliable solution? I don't recall ever seeing these variables referred to in the CMake docs, which makes me think this might not be a safe thing to rely on between versions